# How to kill other applications in Android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to kill other applications when I open my application? For example I am playing some music and I opened my application and trying to kill the other applications using below code. I could not stop the music playing.

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        
    for(RunningAppProcessInfo info:activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()){
        activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String.valueOf(info.pid));
        activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String.valueOf(info.processName));
        
    }
```

I have given permissions in manifest file also. I am not getting any errors also.

Answer (score 0):

Media player application in reference is written by you?
Music wont stop playing because it is being played by the media service not your application. Application just asks the media server(which is an android background service) to start playback through IPC mechanisms. And the application being killed may not have called mediaplayer `stop()` before getting killed.

Comment: No media player application is not written by me.Can i know how stop the audio playing from my application?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? A little detail might help. :)